# Why using a tag in nextjs Link?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

Discovering NextJs, I am wondering why the a tag is needed when creating a link.
Following the tutorial we have this example:

```
<Link href="/"><a>Back to home</a></Link>
```

But the link works even whitout the a tag like `<Link href="/">Back to home</Link>`.

What is the purpose of this a tag? Isn'it redundant with the Link component?

## EDIT (December 2022)

With [NextJS v.13](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#link-component), the `a` tag is no longer needed :

> The  Component no longer requires manually adding an  tag as
> a child. This behavior was added as an experimental option in version
> 12.2 and is now the default. In Next.js 13,  always renders  and allows you to forward props to the underlying tag.

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

// Next.js 12: `<a>` has to be nested otherwise it's excluded
<Link href="/about">
  <a>About</a>
</Link>

// Next.js 13: `<Link>` always renders `<a>` under the hood
<Link href="/about">
  About
</Link>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## It's for semantic html and SEO

This gives your rendered html proper semantics. This will help with your sites over all SEO. You can see examples and full explanation in the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag).

> If the child of Link is a custom component that wraps an  tag, you must add passHref to Link. This is necessary if you’re using libraries like styled-components. Without this, the  tag will not have the href attribute, which might hurt your site’s SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Next.js 13, We don't need use a tag inside nextjs Link, because it's already added as a child of Link tag

You can check in this link
https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#link-component